# Crashlytics: You must install Crashlytics to continue

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics

I get new project. Actually this is the old game project for iOS which using Objective-C. I just continue the project.

**I see this related code in project.**

Run script:

```
./Crashlytics.framework/run <your api key>
```

In app delegate:

```
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>
```

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
[Crashlytics startWithAPIKey:<your api key>];
```

**When I run, I get this error.**

```
2017-01-20 13:26:07.355 run[12507:165303] Crashlytics.framework/run 1.3.14
2017-01-20 13:26:07.732 run[12507:165303] 

Crashlytics: You must install Crashlytics to continue. https://api.crashlytics.com/api/v1/XXX/confirm/com.handholdings.BBB

If this machine is a build server please remove Crashlytics.app if present and use xcodebuild so that big2.app.dSYM is uploaded.
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

There is missing code? How can I fix this? so I can run this project.

Note: I'm using xcode 8. Not using pods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the Mac App: https://fabric.io/downloads/xcode.

Once installed you will be able to find the open xCode Project, install the Crashlytics Framework and integrate it into your application.

Answer (score 0):

(apologies in advance for possible thread necromancy)

The URL in the original answer is no longer functional, since Crashlytics/Fabric was bought by Google and killed in May of 2020. [Source](https://get.fabric.io/#the-roadmap)

The (now dysfunctional) Fabric URL call was, in my case, caused by a Run Script in the app. Go to Project Settings > Build Phases and remove / edit the Crashlytics run script.
That solved the problem for me.